# PySpark:Processing 100000 column dataset

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, kerberos, large-files

I am using Cloudera Spark 2. We have Kerberos implemented in the cluster.

I have a CSV dataset of 400000x100000. It has 500GB.
I have done the following :

- `df = spark.read.csv('largefile.csv',header=Ture,maxCoulmns=100000)`
- `print(df.count())` and saved in spark_test.py
- In terminal `spark2-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster spark_test.py`

---

The spark job is running, I am able to track it in Spark UI and it is keep on running, after 30 minutes or so it is failing.

---

For testing purpose I have tried the above steps with 10 columns dataset and the job completed successfully.

---

Is there any restrictions or configurations to increase the columns that Spark process ?

Comment: How does it fail? Please post an error stack...

Comment: I am unaable to provide the stack trace right now, this job is running in cloudera spark. And we have Kerberos implemented. From logs it is evident that the job is running for extended time. And it has been written that the job is aborted, that means it is aborting by the system policies. Is there any possibility that Kerberos has some configurations like that ? Or does Spark has any limitations in reading this much columns ?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a valid Kerberos ticket after 30 minutes? I would also specify `--principal` and `--keytab` parameters

Comment: Alright, Im afraid, I didn't mention that configs. So how it is working ?

Comment: `spark2-submit --keytab=/path/to/file.keytab --principal=user@domain ...`

Comment: Okay might be this is the issue, I will try this and let you know.

Comment: @MaxU I have tried that but Spark is unable to locate my keytab file. I have my keytab file in HDFS directory /user/vipin/mykeytab.keytab. How would be the path ? I have tried this : `--keytab=hdfs://user/vipin/mykeytab.keytab'`

Comment: most probably your HDFS is kerberized, so you need a keytab in order to access HDFS ;-)

Comment: @MaxU If you dont mind you could tailor one answer with all the information we have ? And also

Comment: @MaxU ..And also I am able to access `hdfs dfs -ls /user/vipin`

Comment: yep, try to find out whether you have an active kerberos ticket after the spark job has failed...

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your Kerberos ticket is getting expired.

Try to specify `principal` and a `keytab` when calling `spark2-submit`:

```
spark2-submit --keytab=/local/path/to/file.keytab --principal=user@domain \
              --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster spark_test.py
```

Comment: Cloudera doc `For secure clusters, Spark History Server automatically uses Kerberos, so there's nothing to configure.Users running Spark applications must first authenticate to Kerberos, using kinit` - which means, first do a `kinit` then enter the password for  the realm, and try to run the above step ?

Comment: ERROR: CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: SIGNAL RECEIVED TERM

Comment: And I increased memoryOverhead , then the error changed to driver has disassociated!